# How to search for only positive range using fuzziness parameter in fuzzy query?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I am working on the elasticsearch fuzzy query.
Here is my query, which is working fine:

```
CURL -XGET 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d ' 
{
    "query": {
       "fuzzy" : {
           "balance" :{ 
              "value" :  20000,
              "fuzziness" :  10000
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

And the search results are getting returned as expected.
The search results includes documents having balance of range 10000 to 30000 i.e +fuzziness >= 20000 >= -fuzziness.

Now my resquirement is to go for searching for only positve range i.e. greater than 20000 only and not lesser than 20000.

I tried using "+fuzziness" parameter, but that returned a ParseException.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `range` query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "balance" : {
                "gte" : 20000,
                "lte" : 30000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That i know it can be done using range. But how can be achieved using fuzzy query?